# Play 2.1 with Guice 3.0 - Access not available outside Controller classes

Tags: dependency-injection, playframework-2.0, guice

Am trying to learn how guice plays with Play 2.1 framework. I have a service to which I need access outside the service package. I have placed the below in Global file

```
 protected Injector configure() {
      injector =  Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(MyService.class).to(MyServiceImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);
            }
        });

        return injector;
    }

    @Override
    public <A> A getControllerInstance(Class<A> clazz) throws Exception {
        return injector.getInstance(clazz);
    }
```

Inside the controller class am able to get to my object by doing below and everything seems to be fine

```
@Inject
MyService serviceObj
```

But elsewhere outside the controller the same object appears to be null. For example I have a core module which takes care of talking to the service. The controller classes hands out the job to the core module. I need to be able to get hold of this MyService obj in the core module classes.

What am I missing here guys?

Thanks
Karthik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had figured a way out to do this.

In my configure method I had to use this

```
  protected Injector configure() {
      injector =  Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                requestStaticInjection(TheClassThatNeedsMyService.class);
            }
        });

        return injector;
    }
```

And in my TheClassThatNeedsMyService I had to just do

```
@Inject MyService serviceObj;
```

Just for reference this is how my Service class looks like

```
@ImplementedBy(MyServiceImpl.class)
public interface MyService{
...
}

@Singleton
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService{
...
}
```

Now am able to get access to my service object whereever I want in my application. Hope it helps someone

Thanks
Karthik

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore in Play 2.4. Do you know what happened to this feature? I've been trying to get Dependency Injection working outside of Controllers in 2.4.x

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to static injection, see the play-guice sample here:

http://typesafe.com/activator/template/play-guice

Guice can be used in a conventional manner with Play.